# Python wont let me plot, any suggestion?

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
filename= "image_data//Banana.jpeg"
img= Image.load_img (filename, target_size = (224, 224)
plt.imshow()
```

When I get when I try to execute above code;

File "", line 4
plt.imshow()
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: you forgot to close brackets `Image.load_img (filename, target_size = (224, 224))`

Answer (score 1):

The `plt.imshow()` function expects an argument - your image. See [the docs](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html) for further info. Call

```
plt.imshow(img)
```

instead.